# How can I vertically align dropdowns with non-dropdown text?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I can't get these to align correctly.  Can you help?

I think I would prefer buttons if possible...  If you have stylistic suggestions for making this look more elegant it would be greatly appreciated.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark fixed-top" role="navigation">
    <a class="navbar-brand mb-0" href="http://cfswarm-main.localtest.me/secure"><strong>Home</strong></a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav ml-auto">
            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                <a href="#" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" id="navbarDropdown" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                    <i class="fas fa-user-cog"></i> Settings <b class="caret"></b>
                </a>
                <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right bg-dark" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                    <a href="http://cfswarm-main.localtest.me/settings/account" class="dropdown-item text-light bg-dark"><i class="fas fa-cog"></i>&nbsp; Account Settings</a>
                    <a href="http://cfswarm-main.localtest.me/settings/user" class="dropdown-item text-light bg-dark"><i class="fas fa-user"></i>&nbsp; User Settings</a>
                    <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                <a href="#" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" id="navbarDropdown" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" role="button" aria-expanded="false">
                    <i class="fab fa-dev"></i> DevTools <b class="caret"></b>
                </a>
                <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right bg-dark" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                    <a href="" class="dropdown-item text-light bg-dark"><strong>ColdBox Perseverance (Joshua 1:9)</strong></a>
                    <a href="http://coldbox.ortusbooks.com" class="dropdown-item text-light bg-dark" target="_blank"><i class="fas fa-book"></i>&nbsp; Help Manual</a>
                    <a href="https://apidocs.coldbox.org/" class="dropdown-item text-light bg-dark" target="_blank"><i class="fas fa-book"></i>&nbsp; CB API docs</a>
                    <a href="https://www.forgebox.io/" class="dropdown-item text-light bg-dark" target="_blank"><i class="fas fa-cloud"></i>&nbsp; ForgeBox</a>
                    <a href="https://boxteam.slack.com/messages" class="dropdown-item text-light bg-dark" target="_blank"><i class="fas fa-slack"></i>&nbsp; Boxteam Slack</a>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a href="http://cfswarm-main.localtest.me/main/logout" class="dropdown-item text-light bg-dark"><i class="fas fa-sign-out-alt"></i>&nbsp; Logout</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

[Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/z76mnckt/)

Comment: I added a demo to play with. The dropdowns don't work. Please verify that your markup matches the Bootstrap docs and update the link when they're fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason your Logout button is not aligning is that you're using `dropdown-item` even though it is not part of the `dropdown` component.  If you swap that class out for the appropriate one: `nav-link` it will align as expected.

So change:

`<a href="http://cfswarm-main.localtest.me/main/logout" class="dropdown-item text-light bg-dark"><i class="fas fa-sign-out-alt"></i>&nbsp; Logout</a>`

To:

`<a href="http://cfswarm-main.localtest.me/main/logout" class="nav-link text-light bg-dark"><i class="fas fa-sign-out-alt"></i>&nbsp; Logout</a>`

As an aside, you can probably replace all of your `&nbsp;` with the margin utility class of `mr-1` (as part of your font awesome class declaration) for better consistency.

Comment: Yep, and also adding the style classes makes it all visually uniform: https://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/z76mnckt/6/

Comment: @isherwood I'm not following you - did you make changes here?  I'm not seeing them.

Comment: Compare the demo I put in the question with that one. The latter has style classes added to the dropdown trigger element so it matches the logout element (hover, etc.).

Comment: Yes it does.  And it looks better now.  Thanks again!